# database phpmyadmin on insert trigger

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Have this SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `account_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `access_level` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `normal_profile` (
  `normal_profileid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `normal_profile`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `normal_profile_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`account_id`);
```

[phpmyadmin ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIjQl.png)

The above is how i set constraints.

Whenever i insert something on to my accounts table, do i also have to query an insert into the normal_profile table? or can i automatically make it so that the DB itself will just add a row into normal_profile where account_id = accounts.account_id?

I have a vague memory of an on insert constraint or maybe im mistaken?

[Adding Trigger UI phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIjQl.png)

Comment: and how is the database supposed to know what goes into the fields that are unrelated??

Comment: I already set account_id as FK in normal_profile table.

Do i have to set more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this syntax

```
delimiter #
     CREATE TRIGGER after_accounts
        AFTER insert ON accounts
         FOR EACH ROW
             BEGIN
          --  your insert query 
           end#

delimiter ;
```

[image]

Comment: I've added an image on adding triggers on phpmyadmin.

Where do i put the SQL query, inside the defintion input?

Comment: you just need to your inset query on definition text area

Comment: is this a better method? 

Or is inserting it manually in php more acceptable?

since my account_id is Auto_Increment, everytime i create a new acc('username','password','email','access_level') ill just call another model function after the model function register is done?

Or is the trigger method more acceptable?

Comment: seriously i suggest you use double query instead of trigger its help you easily debug and its feasible for you as compare triggers